# Javascriptで、日本語の「あいうえお」を文字コードを使って取得したい

Tags: javascript, 文字コード

```
var str1 = String.fromCharCode(65);
```

とすると、str1 → "A"となりますが、これと似たような感じで
文字コードから、"あ"、"い"、"う"、"え"、"お"といった五十音を取得したいです。
どうしたら良いですか？日本語の文字コードの使い方がよく分かりません。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`fromCharCode()` に指定するのは UTF-16 のコードユニットです。平仮名の場合は Unicode のコードポイントと同じです。

コードユニットを調べる方法はいろいろありますが、一例として、ブラウザで以下のようなコードを実行してコンソールを見れば良いでしょう。

```
var input = "あいうえお";
for (let i = 0; i < input.length; ++i) {
  console.log(input[i], input.charCodeAt(i));
}
```

結果:

```
あ 12354
い 12356
う 12358
え 12360
お 12362
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 var str1 = String.fromCharCode(65);
```

と似たような感じで"あ"、"い"、"う"、"え"、"お"といった五十音を取得したい、という事ですから、求めていらっしゃるのは

```
 var str1 = String.fromCharCode(12354, 12356, 12358, 12360,12362);
```

だと思います。
これを実行すると、str1 → "あいうえお"になります。

fromCharCodeの引数を、あ、い、う、え、おのUnicodeをカンマで区切ったものにすれば、"あいうえお"の文字列が得られるという訳です。

ユニコードは、[ユニコード表（10進表示）](http://www.tamasoft.co.jp/ja/general-info/unicode-decimal.html)　などのサイトで確認できます。
ユニコードを10進数で表しているサイトと、16進数で表しているサイトがあるので注意してください（16進数の場合は、最初の 0xをつける必要があります）